# Кастомные представления в Qt

Tags: qt5, model-view

Имеется сложный виджет, который использует модель - субкласс от `QAbstractItemModel` назовем его `XItemModel`. Модель - readonly, для чтения данных используется `QDataWidgetMapper`. Мне хочется иметь более тесную интеграцию модели и виджета,который отображает поля модели. Иными словами я хочу получить функционал реализуемый представлениями, т.е. иметь метод `setModel()` у моего виджета и не использовать никакие `QDataWidgetMapper`. Но при этом такое хитрое представление должно знать что использует не только интерфейс `QAbstractItemModel`, но и `XItemModel`. Проблема для меня с представлениями в том, что я не знаю как сильно кастомизировать их внешний вид. Если я правильно понимаю то мне придется переписывать `paintEvent()`, это мне не подходит так как как я хочу что бы данные отображались так как как это определяет виджет ( иными словами может быть несколько вариантов отображения одной и той же модели, как в случае с `ListView` и `TreeView`, например ). Т.е. мне нужна простота представлений (установил модель и все отображается) с функционалом, который обеспечивает `QDataWidgetMapper` и конкретная реализация виджета. Не могу понять как правильно в qt делать то что я хочу ?)

Comment: Кто-нибудь понял, что ТС хочет?

Comment: =) Я думаю самое простое решение написать базовый класс, сделать ему публичный виртуальный метод setModel() и в нем уже создать привязку к интерфейсу модели XItemModel (через QDataWidgetMapper). И от него уже наследовать свои виджеты, которые определяют какие поля XModelItem отображать. Но есть же представления, вот что меня смущает. Схемой описанной выше мы ломаем model-view фреймворк Qt.